# Strong Integral

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, definition, lebesgue-integral, locally-convex-spaces

Is there a strong(!) notion of integral that can face all of those issues:

- Singularities
- Decay Modes
- Oscillations
- Measure Spaces
- Locally Convex Spaces

For example combining decay modes with oscillations (non Lebesgue non Riemann):
$$f:[1,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}:f(x):=\frac{1}{x}\sin(x)$$
or singularities with oscillations (non Lebesgue non Riemann):
$$g:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}:g(x):=\frac{1}{x}\sin(\frac{1}{x})$$
Moreover the famous one (non Bochner but Riemann):
$$h:[0,1]\to\ell^2([0,1]):h(s):=\chi_{\{s\}}$$

Comment: Is $\chi_{\{s\}}$ the characteristic function of $\{s\}$? $\;$

Comment: Yes ;) the basis vectors $e_s$

Comment: Yes, it is called the [gauge integral](http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~schectex/ccc/gauge/). $\;$

Comment: $\hspace{.03 in}f$ is neither properly Lebesgue integrable nor properly Riemann integrable, but is both improperly Lebesgue integrable and improperly Riemann integrable. $\;$

Comment: @Ricky Demer: corrected ;)

Comment: @RickyDemer: Does the Henstock-Kurzweil integral apply to arbitrary measure spaces? If not it would miss a huge branch...

Comment: No. $\:$ Any sensible integral that applies to arbitrary measure spaces either works differently $\hspace{.65 in}$ depending on whether or not there is a topology on the measure space, or fails to integrate $\hspace{.03 in}f$ and $g$. $\hspace{.51 in}$

Comment: Is there something written in between 'differently' and 'depending'? There is a huge white gap on my screen...

Comment: Can't you just define gauges on measure spaces rather than intervals (as long as the space itself has finite measure)?

Comment: Sort of; apparently the spacing I used renders differently on different computers. $\:$ Do you mean coming up with some notion of "gaugeable measure space", or somehow having the measure induce what's needed? $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: So in my blank gap there should be written 'sort of'? I mean let a gauge map any point to a measurable set containing that point: $t\in\delta(t)\in\Sigma$

Comment: No; what I put in at that point in the comment should create just enough white-space to put 'differently' and 'depending' on different lines; I just wasn't sure whether that counted as "something written in between ...". $\:$ If you did that then for most measure spaces there would be no reason to consider any gauge other than $t\mapsto \{t\}$. $\;\;\;\;$